# Remove white spacing around table header

Tags: css, html

How can I remove the white spacing between each column of my table header with css? I'd like the entire header to be one continuous background color.

HTML snippet:

```
<table class="asset-list">

  <thead>

    <tr>

      <th>Hostname</th>
      <th>IP Address</th>
      <th>Manufacturer</th>
      <th>Model</th>
      <th>Category</th>

    </tr>

  </thead>
```

Here's a link to the project site I'm working on:

http://104.236.173.175/assets/

Comment: Add `border-collapse: collapse` to the `table` element.. also consider using a [CSS reset](http://cssreset.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of methods to consider:

```
border-collapse: collapse

table {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `cell-padding` and `cell-spacing` in css properties